# Python How to check if my PNG files contain 1 parts or multiple parts

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, png

I'm trying to code something that detect if my png files are only one part or contain multiple parts (has transparent between the parts).

[one part png](https://i.ibb.co/hR5sZL3/Genshin-1-part-png.png)

[4 parts png](https://i.ibb.co/4PxK3wL/Genshin-4parts-png.png)

I found some code online, but it always tell me that my png has more than one part.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy import ndimage

def has_multiple_parts(image_path, threshold=10):
    try:
        # Open the image using Pillow
        img = Image.open(image_path)

        # Convert the image to a NumPy array
        img_array = np.array(img)

        # Convert the image to grayscale (if it's not already)
        if len(img_array.shape) == 3:
            img_gray = img.convert('L')
            img_array = np.array(img_gray)

        # Apply binary thresholding to create a mask
        mask = img_array < threshold

        # Label connected components in the mask
        labeled_regions, num_regions = ndimage.label(mask)

        # If there is only one labeled region, it's considered as one part
        return num_regions == 1
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return False


image_path = "c:\\Documents\\Genshin-1-part-png.png"

if has_multiple_parts(image_path):
    print(f"{image_path} has only one part.")
else:
    print(f"{image_path} has more than one part.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have come up with is to use the alpha channel (transparency channel) in order to count the regions. This channel's values are 0 when the image is transparent and 255 when it is opaque. To open an image in RGBA mode I use [OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) library, I don't know if there are other options.

Once the image is opened, you can apply the thresholding to the fourth channel (alpha) to create the mask, and label it with scipy.

Finally, it is important to use the condition `num_regions <= 2` because if:

1. All image is opaque (not a single transparent pixel): then there will be one region and one part.
2. The image has one part, but there are transparent pixels (like the example): then there will be two regions, but just one part.

Here there is the complete code:

```
from scipy import ndimage
import cv2

def has_multiple_parts(image_path, threshold=1):
    try:
        # Open the image using OpenCV in RGBA mode
        img_rgba =  cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

        # Take the alpha channel (transparency)
        alpha_channel = img_rgba[:,:,3]

        # Apply binary thresholding to create a mask
        mask = alpha_channel < threshold

        # Label connected components in the mask
        labeled_regions, num_regions = ndimage.label(mask)

        # If there are one or two labeled region, it means there is just one part
        return num_regions <= 2
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return False


image_path = "Genshin-1-part-png.png"

if has_multiple_parts(image_path):
    print(f"{image_path} has only one part.")
else:
    print(f"{image_path} has more than one part.")
```